# How does std::unordered_map::at work as an lvalue?

Tags: c++, stl, std

Function outputs are usually rvalues, as far as I know. As seen in the example at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/at/, we can map values using an assignment like:

`mymap.at("Mars") = 3396;`

How does something like this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`at()` returns a *reference* to a value in the map.  This is stated as much on the page you linked to:

> ```
> mapped_type& at ( const key_type& k );  
> const mapped_type& at ( const key_type& k ) const;
> ```
>
> **Returns a reference** to the mapped value of the element with key `k` in the `unordered_map`.

Look at the return type.  The `&` means *reference*.

Assigning a value to a reference will assign the value to the thing that is being referred to.  For example:

```
int i = 0;
int &r = i;
r = 3396;
```

Assigning a value to `r` updates `i`.

**UPDATE**: As stated in comments, `at()` is overloaded for `const` and non-`const` `unordered_map` objects.  As such, `mymap.at("Mars") = 3396;` will work only if `mymap` is non-`const`, because the return value is a reference to a non-`const` `mapped_type` and thus is writable.  But it will fail to compile if `mymap` is `const`, because the return value will be a reference to a `const mapped_type` and thus is read-only.  For example:

```cpp
const int i = 0;
const int &r = i;
r = 3396; // ERROR
```

Comment: @FredLarson `unordered_map::operator[]` does not have a `const` overload. `operator[]` inserts a new element if the requested key is not found, and so it cannot modify a `const unordered_map` object (so, `mymap["Mars"] = 3396;` will not compile if `mymap` is `const`). Whereas `unordered_map::at()` does not insert a new element if the key is not found, it throws an exception instead, so it can have a `const` overload.

Comment: @FredLarson I updated my answer to mention the `const` overload of `at()`, though.